# rank of block lower triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank, block-matrices

Let us consider
\begin{equation}
D= 
\begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\
B & C
\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}
where $Ax \neq 0$ with $x \neq 0$ and the number of rows of $A$ can be larger than that of columns.

In this case, does the following equality hold?
\begin{equation}
rank(D) = rank \begin{bmatrix}  A \\ B \end{bmatrix} + rank[C]
\end{equation}

My conjecture is that since $Ax \neq 0$ with $x \neq 0$, the column space spanned by $\begin{bmatrix}  A \\ B \end{bmatrix} $ does not lie on that of $\begin{bmatrix}  0 \\ C \end{bmatrix}$ and hence we obtain the above result. Is this correct?

Comment: How do you define rank? The above assertion can be strengthened slightly.

Comment: "rank" refers to column rank.